# onload triggering too early for ajax content in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a page where the images are supplied dynamically and are scaled with javascript to fit within the appropriate dimensions. This was initially being done with an onload attribute in the img tag, but then I noticed that in IE, the height being returned for the image was much less in some cases than the actual height, which ended up distorting the image. I solved this by finding and resizing all the images after $(window).load() was done, which worked fine for the initial page load, but I also have the page set up to add more content with an ajax call. For the ajax content, I tried some code I found on here that improved the problem, but didn't completely solve it. Here is an example of one of my image tags

```
<img id="img<?php echo $prodModObj->rolloverID; ?>" class="mbImg unsized" src="<?php echo $prodModObj->img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prodModObj->name; ?>" onerror="swapImage(<?php echo $prodModObj->rolloverID; ?>)" />
```

The swapImage function just swaps out the image with a placeholder if there is an error while loading. Here is my JS

```
function swapImage(thisImgID) {
    var imgID = 'img#img' + thisImgID;
    $(imgID).attr('src', '/images/NoImageAvail.jpg');
}

function checkImage(thisImgID, fitDimension, spaceDimension) {
    var imgID = 'img#img' + thisImgID;          
    var imgHeight = $(imgID).height();
    var imgWidth = $(imgID).width();
    var displayHeight, displayWidth, newMargin;

    if (imgHeight > imgWidth) {
       displayHeight = fitDimension;
       displayWidth = imgWidth*(displayHeight/imgHeight);
    } else if (imgHeight < imgWidth) {
       displayWidth = fitDimension;
       displayHeight = imgHeight*(displayWidth/imgWidth);
    } else {
       displayWidth = fitDimension;
       displayHeight = fitDimension;
    }
    $(imgID).css('height', displayHeight);
    $(imgID).css('width', displayWidth);
    newMargin = ((spaceDimension - displayHeight)/2);
    $(imgID).css('margin-top', newMargin);
    $(imgID).removeClass('mbImg unsized').addClass('mbImg sized');
}
```

And then on the page I have

```
$(window).load(function(){

// Resize product images

  $('.mbImg.unsized').each( function() {
     var rolloverID = $(this).attr('id').substr(3);
     checkImage(rolloverID,250,270);
  });

});
```

And then in the success portion of the ajax call, I have

```
$('.mbImg.unsized').each( function() {
     var rolloverID = $(this).attr('id').substr(3);
     if (this.complete) {
         checkImage(rolloverID,250,270);
     } else {
         $(this).on('load', function(){
            checkImage(rolloverID,250,270);
         });                   
     }
});
```

Images that have been cached by the browser work fine, and the images in the initial page load work fine, but about 1 in 5 of new ajax images come out distorted. Is there another method I can use to size all the ajax images correctly in IE?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe come at it another way?

I've tried to move away from html4 style tag syntax, to using simple html5 tags and a combination of JavaScript and CSS to control the "view".

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zacwolf/s1haq3mz/

A question becomes how you want your images to flow, as using this approach all of the images are technically the same size (as demonstrated by the border).  Also note that the .src for the second image I tweeked the url a bit so that it was a 404 for the image file, which triggered the one error image instead.

```
<img id="one" class="myclass" />
<img id="two" class="myclass" />
<style>
.myclass{
    height:270px;
    width:250px;
    background-position:center,center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}
</style>
<script>
var one = new Image();
one.onerror=
    function(){
        this.src='http://leomarketingep.com/wp-content/uploads/Sign-Error-icon.png'
    }
one.onload=
    function(){
        $('#one').css('background-image','url('+one.src+')')
    }
one.src='https://cjjulian.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/blah_blah_blah-703369.jpg';

var two = new Image();
two.onerror=
    function(){
        this.src='http://leomarketingep.com/wp-content/uploads/Sign-Error-icon.png';
    }
two.onload=
    function(){
        $('#two').css('background-image','url('+two.src+')')
    }
two.src='https://cjjulian.files.wordpress.com/2019/04/blah_blah_blah-703369.jpg';
</script>
```

If you have a lot of images, you can populate an array of Image objects, for better referencing, etc.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know about background-size in CSS, but that can be used in so many ways! I will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, if you're used to the pre-HTML5 days of using images and tables for layout, everything that is now possible with CSS can take a bit of getting used to, but it really helps standardize how things look across browsers.  The biggest aspect of using CSS is understand how things flow via "position", "display", and "z-index" which isn't very intuitive.